# React Native AsyncStorage useEffect not responding

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

The following code is supposed to save the data and show it when the button to retrieve is pressed. However it doesn't respond whenever and show the data when pressed. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import { Button, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet,Alert } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// You can import supported modules from npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

// or any files within the Snack
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function App() {
  const [arrayString, setArrayString] = useState("hhh")
  const [arrayObject, setArrayObject] = useState([])

  
  useEffect(() => {
    getTodosFromUserDevice()
  },[arrayObject, arrayString])

  const objectArray = [
    {
        id: Math.random(),
        subtasks: [],
        taskName: 'Task1',
        timeLeft: 10,
        completed: false,
    },
    {
        id: Math.random(),
        subtasks: [],
        taskName: 'Task2',
        timeLeft: 20,
        completed: false,
    },
    {
        id: Math.random(),
        subtasks: [],
        taskName: 'Task3',
        timeLeft: 30,
        completed: false,
    }
  ]


  async function getTodosFromUserDevice() {
    try {
      const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
      const results = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
      setArrayObject(JSON.parse(results));
      setArrayString(results)
      Alert.alert(arrayString)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('GettodoError');
    }
  }


  const saveTodoToUserDevice = async () => {
  try {
    for (const item of objectArray) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(String(item.taskName), JSON.stringify(item));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('SavetodoError', error);
  }
};

const deleteAll = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.clear()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Deletion error', error);
  }
}

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Button title="Save" onPress={saveTodoToUserDevice}>Save</Button>
      <Button title="Retrive and show" onPress={getTodosFromUserDevice}>Retrive and show</Button>
      <Button title="Delete" onPress={deleteAll}> Delete </Button>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
Hellow      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph} >{arrayObject}</Text>
      <Text>{arrayString}</Text>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

The following code is supposed to save the data and show it when the button to retrieve is pressed. However it doesn't respond whenever and show the data when pressed. Any advice would be appreciated.